# Binding to dependency property inside of a style

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I need a button with custom style and i would like to have an image on it.

So i have made CustomButton style with ControlTemlate containing StackPanel of TextBlock for text and Rectangle for image, i want to use DrawingImage from my Icons.xaml, it is SVG converted to XAML.

I have also made CustomButton class, it is derived from the regular Button class and has DrawingImageProperty which is dependency property.

In my view i want to create this button with DrawingImage property and then bind to this property in my style, something like this:

```
<controls:CustomButton DrawingImage="{StaticResource Add}" Content="Add" Style="{StaticResource CustomButton}" />
```

But unfortunately the button image is missing. I am not sure about binding to the dependency property in the style and also i am not sure about the types, because Drawing property of the DrawingBrush is of type Drawing, but in my Icons.xaml resources i have DrawingImage, couldn't this be also problem?

CustomButton.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Torch.Controls">
    <Style x:Key="CustomButton" TargetType="{x:Type controls:CustomButton}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource IconicWhiteBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type controls:CustomButton}">
                    <Border
                        Name="Border"
                        Background="{StaticResource IconicBlueLittleDarkBrush}"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource IconicBlackBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="1">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Rectangle Width="20" Height="20">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <DrawingBrush Drawing="{TemplateBinding DrawingImage}" />
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <TextBlock
                                Margin="0,0,5,0"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

CustomButton.cs

```
public class CustomButton : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DrawingImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DrawingImage", typeof(DrawingImage), typeof(CustomButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnDrawingImageChanged));

    public DrawingImage DrawingImage
    {
        get => (DrawingImage)GetValue(DrawingImageProperty);
        set => SetValue(DrawingImageProperty, value);
    }

    private static void OnDrawingImageChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((CustomButton)d).DrawingImage = (DrawingImage)e.NewValue;
    }
}
```

Icons.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <DrawingImage x:Key="Add">
        <DrawingImage.Drawing>
            <DrawingGroup ClipGeometry="M0,0 V24 H24 V0 H0 Z">
                <GeometryDrawing Brush="#FF00ACC1" Geometry="F1 M24,24z M0,0z M19,13L13,13 13,19 11,19 11,13 5,13 5,11 11,11 11,5 13,5 13,11 19,11 19,13z" />
            </DrawingGroup>
        </DrawingImage.Drawing>
    </DrawingImage>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DrawingImage is not a Drawing, hence

```
Drawing="{TemplateBinding DrawingImage}"
```

can not work. Use an Image element instead, and bind its Source property.

```
<Image Source="{TemplateBinding DrawingImage}"/>
```

---

Besides that, the `OnDrawingImageChanged` callback is pointless. It assigns a value to the property which it already has. You can safely remove it.

I'd also use `ImageSource` instead of `DrawingImage` as type of the dependency property. You could use it more flexibly and also assign other image types like `BitmapImage`.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Image), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(CustomButton));

public ImageSource Image
{
    get => (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty);
    set => SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
}
```

In the ControlTemplate:

```
<Image Source="{TemplateBinding Image}"/>
```

Comment: I have replaced the `Rectangle` with `Image` and it now works perfectly, thank you very much and also big thanks for poiting out the other things :-).